# Number fields with prescriped prime decomposition

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Pick your favorite prime $p$, as well as three positive integers $e,f,g$.

For each such choice, does there exist at least one Galois number field $K/\mathbf{Q}$ of degree $n=efg$  in which $p$ has ramification index $e$ and inertial degree $f$?

Comment: I think there’s a “trivial” local obstruction due to ramification theory: the prime-to-$p$ part of $e$ must divide $p^f-1$.

Comment: @Aphelli Good point; I'm most interested in the case where $e$ is 1.

Comment: This well-known to be false for $p=2$ and $(e,f,g) = (1,8,1)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunwald%E2%80%93Wang_theorem#A_consequence_of_Wang's_counter-example

Answer (score 4):

Yes for odd primes in the case $e=1$, and you can take $K$ to be cyclic, and this is also true relatively to any base number field and for any finite collection of primes. It follows from the Grunwald-Wang theorem, according to which every finite collection of local cyclic extensions at distinct primes can be globalised into a single cyclic extension of degree the LCM of the local degrees (See Artin-Tate, *Class field theory*, Chapter X, Section 2, Theorem 5).

Comment: This feels like a result I should have known, but definitely did not know. Thanks so much!

Comment: degree the LCM of the local degrees, possibly times 2.

Comment: @user491858 No, the times 2 occurs only when you want to globalise characters, but you don't need it to globalise field extensions (see Theorem 6 in Artin-Tate).

Comment: @user491858 Oh sorry, that's not true. You can ensure that the local extension has the right degree, but not necessarily that it is unramified. So there is indeed the times 2 if you insist on unramifiedness. I've edited to add "odd", so that the bad case is avoided.